# Seaborn Heatmap Color By Row

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have a network graph.

[image: network]

Each node is a case and each edge is a CPT.

I used `community.best_partition` to break the graph into four communities (noted by their colors).

To better visualize the shared CPTs and case volumes in each community I used `plt.subplots` and `sns.heatmap` to create four heatmaps with similar matching colors between communities.

[image: heatmap]

Code to produce the heatmaps:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=4, figsize=(16,8), sharex=True)

cmaps = ['Blues', 'Oranges', 'Greens', 'Reds']

comms = range(4)

for ax, cmap, comm in zip(axs, cmaps, comms):
    sns.heatmap(
        data=_.loc[[comm]],
        ax=ax,
        cmap=cmap,
        annot=True,
        annot_kws={
            'fontsize' : 12
        },
        fmt='g',
        cbar=False,
        robust=True,
    )

    ax.set_ylabel('Community')

    ax.set_xlabel('');
```

**Question**

Is there a way in `sns.heatmap` to specify colors by row (in this case, community) without having to create 4 separate heatmaps?

Here is some sample data:

```
cpt   52320  52353  52310  49568  50432  52234  52317  50435  52354  52332
comm                                                                      
0       NaN    3.0    NaN    1.0    1.0    NaN    2.0    2.0    NaN    3.0
1       1.0   30.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN    NaN    NaN   20.0
2       NaN    NaN  160.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3       NaN    7.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0   12.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do that using seaborn's heatmap, but you can recreate the output using `imshow()`

```
d = """      52320  52353  52310  49568  50432  52234  52317  50435  52354  52332                                                                     
0       NaN    3.0    NaN    1.0    1.0    NaN    2.0    2.0    NaN    3.0
1       1.0   30.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN    NaN    NaN   20.0
2       NaN    NaN  160.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3       NaN    7.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0   12.0"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep='\\s+')

N_communities = df.index.size
N_cols = df.columns.size
cmaps = ['Blues', 'Oranges', 'Greens', 'Reds']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i,((idx,row),cmap) in enumerate(zip(df.iterrows(), cmaps)):
    ax.imshow(np.vstack([row.values, row.values]), aspect='auto', extent=[-0.5,N_cols-0.5,i,i+1], cmap=cmap)
    for j,val in enumerate(row.values):
        vmin, vmax = row.agg(['min','max'])
        vmid = (vmax-vmin)/2
        if not np.isnan(val):
            ax.annotate(val, xy=(j,i+0.5), ha='center', va='center', color='black' if (val<=vmid or vmin==vmax) else 'white')
ax.set_ylim(0,N_communities)

ax.set_xticks(range(N_cols))
ax.set_xticklabels(df.columns, rotation=90, ha='center')

ax.set_yticks(0.5+np.arange(N_communities))
ax.set_yticklabels(df.index)
ax.set_ylabel('Community')

ax.invert_yaxis()

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Noticed that the value `160` in Community 2 is barely visible. Expect that is because there's only value in the sample data?

Comment: That's right, the code was not very robust if there were only one value on the row (or if all the values are equal). I've amended my answer with an additional test to take into account this eventuality.

Comment: Note that you probably want to use `ax.annotate(f'{val:.0f}', ..` or something similar to avoid the trailing `.0`. When the cells get too narrow, one could add `ax.annotate(..., rotation=90)`