# Use two colors to color different rows in seaborn heatmap split the rows into two

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I have the following dataframe:

```
fruits={'fruit':['apple1','apple2','banana1','banan2','peach1','peach2'],'1':[0,0,0,1,0,1],'2':[1,1,0,1,1,1],'3':[1,1,1,1,0,0],'4':[0,1,1,1,1,1]}
df_fruits=pd.DataFrame(data=fruits)
df_fruits=df_fruits.set_index('fruit')


>>>     1   2   3   4
fruit               
apple1  0   1   1   0
apple2  0   1   1   1
banana1 0   0   1   1
banan2  1   1   1   1
peach1  0   1   0   1
peach2  1   1   0   1
```

I'm Trying to create some kind of heatmap so if value is 1 it will get color and if is zero will get color grey.In addition to that, and here is the problem, I want to give all the fruits with number one color blue and all the fruits with number two color green.
I have tried to use the script as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60325792/seaborn-heatmap-color-by-row) but I get white lines on the cells in undesired locations that divide each row into two:

```
N_communities = df_fruits.index.size
N_cols = df_fruits.columns.size
cmaps = ['Blues','Greens','Blues','Greens','Blues','Greens','Blues','Greens','Blues','Greens','Blues','Greens','Blues','Greens','Blues','Greens','Blues','Greens','Blues','Greens','Blues','Greens','Blues','Greens','Blues','Greens','Blues','Greens','Blues','Greens']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

for i,((idx,row),cmap) in enumerate(zip(df_fruits.iterrows(), cmaps)):
    ax.imshow(np.vstack([row.values, row.values]), aspect='equal', extent=[-0.5,N_cols-0.5,i,i+1], cmap=cmap)
    for j,val in enumerate(row.values):
        vmin, vmax = row.agg(['min','max'])
        vmid = (vmax-vmin)/2
        #if not np.isnan(val):
            #ax.annotate(val, xy=(j,i+0.5), ha='center', va='center', color='black' if (val<=vmid or vmin==vmax) else 'white')
ax.set_ylim(0,N_communities)

ax.set_xticks(range(N_cols))
ax.set_xticklabels(df_fruits.columns, rotation=90, ha='center')

ax.set_yticks(0.5+np.arange(N_communities))
ax.set_yticklabels(df_fruits.index)
ax.set_ylabel('Index')
ax.hlines([2,4],color="black" ,*ax.get_xlim())
ax.invert_yaxis()

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

As you can see, it looks like apple 1 has two rows and apple 2 has two rows and etc., while I want to have one row per each.
I have tried to play with the extent but could not ger rid of those lines.

**My end goal - to have one rows in the heatmap for each row in the dataframe**, when fruit finishes with 1 are blue, fruits finishes with 2 are green (only if value is 1) . if value is zero it will be grey.

**Edit:**
I have used the the ax.grid(False)  as suggested but is still not goood as the lines dissapear. also I found out that the plotting is wrong:
[image]

as you can see, the row "banana2" suppose to get green color but is white.

Comment: `ax.grid(False)`?

Comment: @DavidG I want to have grid but on the right way, This cancelles all the grid lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `mask` option of [**`sns.heatmap`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

> `mask`: If passed, data will not be shown in cells where `mask` is `True`. Cells with missing values are automatically masked.

So, to plot the blue fruit1 squares, `mask` out the fruit2 values and vice versa.

The fruit1/fruit2 heatmaps can be plotted together by saving the axes handle `ax` and reusing it with `ax=ax`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

fruits = {'fruit':['apple1','apple2','banana1','banana2','peach1','peach2'],'1':[0,0,0,1,0,1],'2':[1,1,0,1,1,1],'3':[1,1,1,1,0,0],'4':[0,1,1,1,1,1]}
df_fruits = pd.DataFrame(data=fruits)
df_fruits = df_fruits.set_index('fruit')

# *** this line is needed for seaborn 0.10.1 (not needed for 0.11.1) ***
df_fruits = df_fruits.astype('float')

# common settings: linewidths for grid lines, hide colorbar, set square aspect
kwargs = dict(linewidths=1, cbar=False, square=True)

# plot initial gray squares and save heatmap handle as ax
ax = sns.heatmap(df_fruits, cmap='Greys_r', alpha=0.2, **kwargs)

# iterate ending:cmap pairs
cmaps = {'1': 'Blues_r', '2': 'Greens_r'}
for ending, cmap in cmaps.items():
    
    # create mask for given fruit ending
    mask = df_fruits.apply(
        lambda x: x if x.name.endswith(ending) else 0,
        result_type='broadcast',
        axis=1,
    ).eq(0)
    
    # plot masked heatmap on reusable ax
    sns.heatmap(df_fruits, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, ax=ax, **kwargs)
```

[image: fruit heatmap]

Comment: Hey, I have tried your script on the fruit dataframe but it had no colors , only grey

Comment: the last part if plot the masked heatmap result in error: TypeError: Cannot convert fill_value nan to dtype int64.

Comment: You mean with the sample dataframe or your real data? If you're getting the error with the sample df, maybe it's a version issue -- what's your `sns.__version__` and `pd.__version__`? If it's from your real data, can it be made public? If so then I could check the issue there.

Comment: no, is with the fruit smple . seaborn version 0.10.1 and pandas version 1.1.13

Comment: Ok I edited the answer with the fix for seaborn `0.10.1`, just one extra line near the top converting `.astype('float')`